# Help with corrupted Msn chat history xml files

Tags: xml

the problem is since msn saves chat records in an xml file sometimes this xml file gets corrupted and all the past conversations are lost, if xml file is opened, it gives some kind of error "The XML page cannot be displayed Cannot view XML input".

error like that . pls i want to open the conversations need help here important.

Comment: when the xml is saving are you getting any exceptions in logs or in console?

Comment: nope . ya i chked at end it was <messa only i removed it and put </message></Log> and its fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open the xml file in notepad . Go to end. the end should be `</message></Log>` it is where it gets bugged. put this in end and everything will be fixed.